# React Native - NavigatorIOS and TabBarIOS implementation

Tags: react-native

I 'm still warming up on React Native and I've a very basic doubt. I just need to place tab bar and navigator on the same screen. But the tab bar is basically overriding the nav bar and the view content is starting at top: 0 instead start bellow of the nav bar. Any good help for me ?

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var RootNav = require('./root.ios');
var {
 AppRegistry,
 StyleSheet,
 View,
 NavigatorIOS,
 TabBarIOS
  } = React;

var memopal = React.createClass({
render: function() {
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
  <NavigatorIOS style={styles.nav} initialRoute={{
    title : 'my root',
    component: RootNav
  }}/>
  <TabBarIOS style={styles.tabBar}>
      <TabBarIOS.Item>

      </TabBarIOS.Item>
      <TabBarIOS.Item>

      </TabBarIOS.Item>
    </TabBarIOS>
  </View>
  );
 }
 });

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
 container: {
  flex: 1,
  backgroundColor: '#FF0000'
 },
 tabBar:  {
 backgroundColor: '#00FF00',
 flex: 1,
 justifyContent: 'center',
 alignItems: 'center',
 width: 20,
 height: 20
 }
});

 AppRegistry.registerComponent('memopal', () => memopal);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume, that you want to use a single TabBar in your whole application and a NavigatorIOS separately for each TabBarIOS.Item.

## Source

```
var memopal = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <TabBarIOS>
                <TabBarIOS.Item
                    selected={true}
                    title="View1"
                >
                    <NavigatorIOS
                        style={styles.nav}
                        initialRoute={{
                            title : 'my root',
                            component: RootNav
                           }}
                    />
                </TabBarIOS.Item>
                <TabBarIOS.Item>
                </TabBarIOS.Item>
            </TabBarIOS>
        );
    }
 });

AppRegistry.registerComponent('memopal', () => memopal);
```

## Result

[image: TabBarIOS with NavigatorIOS]

Comment: Yes...you are right...I think I'm making some mistaken of interface concept instead implementation concept !!! ty !!!